# this.props.onAdd is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-props

I try to nest a component with a form to add records to the database, within a component that lists everything, but pressing submit gives me this error: "Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onAdd is not a function."
I have reviewed everything from top to bottom, but I don't see the problem, since it is A method that I used before without problems, but i'm new at this, so...
I'm using Laravel in the backend (in case you need to know).

Can somebody help me please?

thanks for your time!!

This is my father component:

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Empresa from './Empresa';
import CrearEmpresa from './CrearEmpresa';



export default class Empresas extends Component {

constructor() {

super();

this.state = {
    empresas: [],
    empresaActual: null
  }
this.handleAddEmpresa = this.handleAddEmpresa.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {

    fetch('/api/empresas')
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(empresas => {

            this.setState({ empresas });
        });
}

renderEmpresas() {
    return this.state.empresas.map(empresa => {
        return (

    <div className="card" key={empresa.id}>

    <div className="card-body">
        <h5 className="card-title">{empresa.nombre}</h5>
        <p className="card-text">{empresa.cif} </p>

        <p className="card-text">{empresa.direccion} </p>
        <p className="card-text"> {empresa.telefono} </p>
        <p className="card-text"> {empresa.mail}</p>
        <p className="card-text"> {empresa.entradas}</p>

    </div>
    <div className="card-footer">
        <a onClick={()=>this.handleClick(empresa)} >Más</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    );
  })
}
handleClick(empresa) {

this.setState({empresaActual:empresa});

}

handleAddEmpresa (empresa) {
    empresa.entradas = Number(empresa.entradas);
    fetch( 'api/empresas/', {
        method:'post',

        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },

        body: JSON.stringify(empresa)
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {

        this.setState((prevState)=> ({
            empresas: prevState.empresas.concat(data),
            empresaActual : data
        }))
    })

  }

render() {

return (
<div className="container" id="empresas" >
    <div className="row">
        <div className="col s12 offset-m l8">
            <h3> Empresas </h3>
            { this.renderEmpresas() }
        </div>
        <Empresa empresa={this.state.empresaActual} />


    </div>
        <div>
        <CrearEmpresa onAdd={this.handleAddEmpresa} />
        </div>

</div>

);
}
}
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
And this is the child:

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
import React, {Component} from 'react';



export default class CrearEmpresa extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

         this.state = {
            nuevaEmpresa: {
                nombre: '',
                direccion: '',
                telefono: '',
                mail: '',
                entradas: 0
            }
          }


      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }


    handleChange  (e){
        this.setState ({
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(this.state);
      this.props.onAdd(this.state.nuevaEmpresa);

    }

    render() {


      return(
        <div>
    <div className="container">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="transparent">
            <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Nueva Empresa</h5>
            <div className="input-field">
                <label htmlFor="nombre">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
            <div className="input-field">
                <label htmlFor="direccion">Dirección</label>
                <textarea className="materialize-textarea" name="direccion" id="direccion"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}></textarea>
            </div>
            <div className="input-field">
                <label htmlFor="telefono">Teléfono</label>
                <br />
                <input type="tel" name="telefono" id="telefono" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
            <div className="input-field">
                <label htmlFor="mail">Mail</label>
                <br />
                <input type="email" name="mail" id="mail" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>


            <div className="input-field">
                <label htmlFor="entradas">Número de entradas</label>
                <input type="number" name="entradas" id="entradas" min="10" max="50000" step="5"
                    onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>


            <input type="submit" value="submit" />

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
      )
    }
  }

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: I'm try to reproducing you error, but same code work for me: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-payne-ol5u6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Ok, thanks Fiodorov Andrei

Comment: The code example helped you to find bug ?

Comment: No, I'm still trying to figure it out

Comment: Why you treat tour props like you using redux if you wanna treat your function as props you better use redux and put your logic in action reducers.